# Android Java, bitmap from resources

Tags: android

I have my images in my res/drawable folder, there's no problem about that.
The thing is, i'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.*img[contar]*);
```

In other words eclipse doesn't let me do this `img[contar]` it only accepts the specific name of the image file (example: crystalblue), and i'd like to lets say move from "crystalblue" to "crystalred" image and in my case i need a variable to do it.

Obs: I did declare img as string array.

Any solutions anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant' concatenate half of a variable name with runtime data. The compiler can't tell what variable you're actually trying to pass.

what you have to do is something like this:

```
int resourceId = 0;
if(someCondition){
  resourceId = R.drawable.someimage;
}else{
  //other logic for picking the right image here
}

mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId);
```

You could also use reflection to find the field within the R class that has a name that matches the value in your string array and then do a "get" call on that to populate resourceId:

```
Class rClass = R.drawable.class;
Field resourceConstant =rClass.getField(img[contar]);       
int resourceId = resourceConstant.getInt(null); //since it's a static field, pass null here
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId);
```

Comment: yes, you're right. i'd like to tell the way i did it, but i don't have enough reputation, so i'll be answering this after 5 hours!!! lol

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some kind of this can helps: (img[conter] for example is "red" or "blue")

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("crystal"+img[contar], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    if(id!=0)
      someImageView.setImageResource(id);
    else
      someImageView.setImageBitmap(null);
```

or get Bitmap

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow! I just posted this and the responses were realy quick! 
I was wating to be answered days later! Thank you so much.
In fact i managed to find the solution out by myself before coming here, and here's what i now understand, example:

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.crystalblue);
```

This part here "R.drawable.crystalblue" means that it goes to the generated file "R" and under "drawable" it looks for the value of "crystalblue" which happens to be an "int" kind of value.

So what i did was, i took these values (which represents the images i wanted) and put them in an int array:

```
int imgRef[] = {0x7f020000, 0x7f020002, 0x7f020003, 0x7f020004, 0x7f020005, 0x7f020006};
```

and finally:

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgRef[count]);
```